# Use of Tokens on flutter

Tags: flutter, api, https, token

I´m new in this site and in flutter, I´m trying to get connected to an API,and I have been running into issues with white spaces I´m using uri.https, and im currently using single and double quotes because that's the only way I found I can avoid the "+" from show in the white space ok the TOKEN. whithout that I receive this error.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Having say it that this is my code:

```
String _token='"Token 25e94e9fc7d38d6a10bb9328fb07546881602467"';
```

```
final Map<String, String> header={
   'Authorization':_token
 };
```

```
final response = await http.post(url,headers:header,body: json.encode(androidid));
final Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(response.body.toString());
print(decodedResp);
print(response.statusCode);
print(header);
```

and after that I get this:

I/flutter (24825): {detail: Authentification credentials were not provided.}
I/flutter (24825): 401
I/flutter (24825): {Authorization: "Token 25e94e9fc7d38d6a10bb9328fb07546881602467"}

it supose that the API is waiting for something as {Authorization: Token 25e9............

I have been trying  to the request in that way, ´cause I´m working on a team and it´s like they´re waiting that I process the data, I´m not even sure if it´s possible do it in that way(using the word and the number)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that "Token" should be inside a token

Comment: That was my first thought, , did you have been working your code in that way?(without the word token? )